Why do I have both phpMyAdmin and MySQL Databases in cPanel? I only used phpMyAdmin locally for development. with Real life exmple please
I’ve been using phpMyAdmin locally for developing my project, and I’m now working with cPanel for hosting. I noticed that cPanel provides two tools for managing MySQL databases:
phpMyAdmin – This is a web interface I’ve been using to interact with my databases (view data, run queries, etc.).
MySQL Databases – I’ve also seen this option, which seems to allow me to create databases, users, and assign permissions.
But here’s my confusion:
Why do I need both tools?
I only used phpMyAdmin locally on my development machine, and I never needed something like MySQL Databases before. Now that I’m using cPanel, I don’t understand the distinction or when I should use MySQL Databases vs. phpMyAdmin.
I understand phpMyAdmin helps me interact with the data visually, but what’s the role of MySQL Databases? Do I need to use it just to create databases and users, or can I do everything through phpMyAdmin?
For example, if I want to create a factory_db database for my project:
Do I use MySQL Databases to create it and set up users?
Then do I use phpMyAdmin to manage the data, tables, and queries?
Is there a reason why cPanel has both tools, and how should I use them together for web development?
Thanks for any clarification!

These are database admin tools, you must not use either of these for application development. You have to deploy your database creation and modification from code (sql or otherwise) or via a database change management tool, like liquibase.

Otherwise, cpanel's website tells you the difference between these two tools: https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/databases/mysql-databases Took a whopping 30 secs to find it...

Actually i know that i can not use it in development mode. but as much as i research i can not find any article or something to erad and learn about and how to use that is why i asked here.

login to php
myuser_factory_db
make table: produktos
-id (int)
-name (varchar)
-quantity (intk)
run queries.

cpanel:
-database: myuser_factory_db
-user: myuser_factory_admin
-permissions: all priv.

phpMyAdmin:
-access myuser_factory_db
-make inventory
-import initial data
-manage daily operations

REALLIFE EXPIERIENCE::
my web is this one - used it and it works normally
